# COMMANDO de DUMP do MySQL no VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Pessoal boa noite preciso dar esse comando no SHELL do VB.NET 
mas não estou conseguindo fazê-lo já tentei umas 3 horas li muitas coisas e não consigo pensar fora da caixa .

```
Shell("CMD.exe /c cd \ & cd Program Files & cd MAPS & cd SERVER MANAGER & cd mysql & cd bin & mysqldump --user=root --password=x maps.controller > "C:\Program Files\MAPS\SERVER MANAGER\mysql\dumped\1.sql" ", AppWinStyle.Hide = 1)
```

Ele fica com erro na hora de programar tenho que pensar em algo diferente mas não consigo alguém tem uma luz ai , já tentei colocar via string nomeando STRING fora e puxando pra dentro mas na hora do comando mysqldump ele precisa ser lido exatamente como esse no [DOS] .

```
mysqldump --user=root --password=x maps.controller > "C:\Program Files\MAPS\SERVER MANAGER\mysql\dumped\1.sql"
```

no DOS esse comando é perfeito dentro do VB.NET que eu não consigo colocar .

---

no VB.NET ATUALMENTE está assim para criar; Porém cria em um local que eu não quero que é a pasta raiz do mysqldump.exe  :

```
Private Sub BackupMAPSCONTROLLERDBToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BackupMAPSCONTROLLERDBToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim ano, mes, dia As Integer
    Dim data_corrente As Date
    Dim data_corrente_saida As String

    data_corrente = dtp1.Value
    dia = data_corrente.Day
    mes = data_corrente.Month
    ano = data_corrente.Year
    data_corrente_saida = dia & "-" & mes & "-" & ano

    Shell("CMD.exe /c cd \ & cd Program Files & cd MAPS & cd SERVER MANAGER & cd mysql & cd bin & mysqldump --user=root --password=x maps.controller > " & "MAPS_CONTROLLER-" & data_corrente_saida & ".sql", AppWinStyle.Hide = 1)
End Sub
```